# Is there a word in the English language that means "can be used as a weapon"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

Is there a word in the English language that means "that can be used as a weapon"?

As in:

- That can be disposed = disposable
- That can be thrown = throwable

Comment: That can be wielded (as a weapon).

Comment: In the above example, it seems the word "used" would actually be the part of the sentence that would be converted to "usable." In the example, we are starting with a verb rather than a noun, which may be causing a slight obstacle. I'll keep thinking on it.

Comment: Yeah the examples are cheating. The analogy does not work, because it's not an analogy.

Answer (score 3):

In military circles, anyway, there is a term "weaponize" past tense "weaponized" (British spelling "weaponise" past tense "weaponised") which means "be turned into a weapon". I've specifically heard it used with respect to Anthrax spores, and an internet search shows it is also used with attempts to use animals for destructive military purposes.

Comment: Would _weaponise_ not rather be likely to mean ‘be turned into a weapon’, so that something that **can** be turned into a weapon would be _weaponisable_?

Comment: Exactly what I thought. "We can weaponize the flag." == We can turn the flag into a weapon. "The flag is weaponizable" == It can be turned into a weapon.

Comment: Weaponising to me would imply altering a non weapon to become a weapon. So "things that can be used as a weapon" actually includes three groups. (1) Non weapons that have been weaponised. (2) Non weapons that have not been specifically altered but are used as a weapon anyway. (3) actual weapons.

Answer (score 1):

One can brandish a lead pipe, a trashcan lid, a lamp, and even a toaster. All of these items are *brandishable*.

> ***Brandish***
>
> Wave or flourish (something, especially a weapon) as a threat or in anger or excitement.
>
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brandish)

The word *brandish* connotes that the thing being held is both visible to others and perceived as threatening. The thing in particular has been "weaponized" to some extent.

It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it may be helpful for describing certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

For something to be used as a weapon, it must inflict damage or harm. It appears the Question asks for a word that is an adjective form (disposable) of a verb (disposed).

Deadly is the closest I can come, for example, "That garbage can lid is weaponizable or deadly, dangerous, life-threatening.

It appears that there are other cases where there are not readily-available words to describe "turning [something] into [something]" or "converting" [something], which makes me wonder if the difference is between a passive and active sentence. I would think there are many scenarios where it might be more efficient to have a word to describe **"*[noun] that can be used as...[a noun]*"** but I can't seem to find many, or any.

For example:

weapon > weaponize > weaponizable, e.g., "That flag is weaponizable."

table > tableize > tableizable, e.g., "The plank of wood on the rocks is tableizable."

shelter > shelterize > shelterizable, e.g., "That cave is shelterizable."

**Passive**: The cake was eaten by the dog. **Active**:  The dog ate the cake.

**Passive**: The garbage can lid was weaponizable.  **Active**: The weapon was the garbage can lid.

**Passive**: That cave is shelterizable or That cave can be the shelter.  **Active**:  The shelter is the cave.

I hope I'm accurate in my analogies and clear in my thoughts.